# Can a women make a condition in the kiddushin?

Tags: halacha

A man can tell a woman to marry me on condition X and if its fulfilled the kiddushin is valid. Can a woman during kiddushin say she will only marry the guy based on a certain condition?

Found the answer Shulchan Aruch (also in the Rambam):
Siman 38
1
המקדש על תנאי וכל דיני תנאי ובו לט סעיפים:
המקדש על תנאי אם נתקיים התנאי מקודשת ואם לאו אינה מקודשת **בין שיהיה התנאי מן האיש בין שיהיה מן *האשה***:

Comment: Yes, she can.the general rule is, if one can make a shliach she can make a condition.

Comment: Pretty sure she can. I believe the Gemara in kiddushin even discusses cases of women who made conditions like “I’ll marry you on the condition that you are a kohen” and then they turned out to be untrue and so on so the Gemara discusses the law.

Comment: @CuriousYid the Gemara is in Kiddushin 49